# How do I pass a selected ID to my SQL Database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc

I am having trouble with this last part of my project. I have all of my SQL Table columns filled up except for this last part. I have two tables WorkSchedule and WorkShiftBid.

In WorkShiftBid, I have WorkShiftBidID,WSBidDateTime,WSBidStatus,WorkScheduleID,StaffID
I will be using Guid.NewGuid() for WorkShiftBidID, Datetime.now for WSBidDatetime, A hardcoded "pending" value for WSBidStatus, A viewbag for StaffID and I am trying to get the WorkScheduleID to work but to no avail.

For WorkSchedule, I am trying to get just the "WorkScheduleID" attribute just by using a button method asp-route-id="@item.WorkScheduleID" and it will redirect me to the Create page whereby I will select a Staff from the drop-down list and then save it to my WorkShiftBid table as it has a foreign key for "WorkScheduleID".

It would be helpful if someone could help me. Thank you.

[image]

Controller Code:

```
  public IActionResult CreateWorkShift()
            {
                ViewData["StaffID"] = new SelectList(_context.Staff, "StaffID", "StaffName");
                return View();
            }
   
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateWorkShift(Guid? id, [Bind("WorkShiftBidID,WSBidDateTime,WSBidStatus,WorkScheduleID,StaffID")] WorkShiftBidModel workShiftBidModel)
    {
        if (id != workShiftBidModel.WorkScheduleID)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            workShiftBidModel.WSBidDateTime = DateTime.Now;
                workShiftBidModel.WorkShiftBidID = Guid.NewGuid();
                _context.Add(workShiftBidModel);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(DisplaySchedule)); 
        } 

        ViewData["StaffID"] = new SelectList(_context.Staff, "StaffID", "StaffName", workShiftBidModel.StaffID);
        return View(workShiftBidModel);
    }

    private bool WorkShiftBidModelExist(Guid id)
    {
        return _context.WorkSchedule.Any(e => e.WorkScheduleID == id);
    }
```

Display WorkShift Page:

```
<h1 class="text-center"> Apply Workshifts</h1>
<hr />

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                From (DateTime)
            </th>
            <th>
                To (DateTime)
            </th>
            <th>
                Day
            </th>
            <th>
                Status
            </th>
            <th>
                Work Descriptions
            </th>
            <th>
                Branch
            </th>
            <th>
                Manager
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.WorkScheduleFromDateTime)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.WorkScheduleToDateTime)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.WorkScheduleFromDateTime.DayOfWeek)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.WorkScheduleStatus)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.WorkDescriptions.WorkDescriptionName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Branches.BranchName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Staff.StaffName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <form method="post">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="Bid" asp-route-id="@item.WorkScheduleID" asp-action="DisplaySchedule" asp-controller="PartTimer" />
                    </form>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <a asp-action="CreateWorkShift" asp-route-id="@item.WorkScheduleID" class="btn btn-success">Create</a>
                    </div>
                </td>   
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Create view page code:

```
<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>Work Shifts</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="CreateWorkShift">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="WorkScheduleID"/>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="WSBidStatus" class="control-label"></label>
                <input readonly asp-for="WSBidStatus" value="Pending" class="form-control"/>
                <span asp-validation-for="WSBidStatus" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="StaffID" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="StaffID" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.StaffID"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <a asp-action="ProfilePage" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block"><i class=" fa fa-table"></i>Back to List</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>



@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you cannot get the `WorkScheduleID` in `public async Task<IActionResult> CreateWorkShift(Guid? id, [Bind("WorkShiftBidID,WSBidDateTime,WSBidStatus,WorkScheduleID,StaffID")] WorkShiftBidModel workShiftBidModel)`.If so,you need to get and pass Id in `public IActionResult CreateWorkShift`.Here is a demo worked:

```
public IActionResult CreateWorkShift(int id)
        {
            List<Staff> list = new List<Staff> { new Staff { StaffID = 1, StaffName = "staff1" }, new Staff { StaffID = 2, StaffName = "staff2" } };
            ViewData["StaffID"] = new SelectList(list, "StaffID", "StaffName");
            WorkShiftBidModel w = new WorkShiftBidModel { WorkScheduleID = id };
            return View(w);
        }
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Sorry, I should've been more clearer. I need to insert a new data into my WorkShiftBidTable, when I try to save it. It doesn't create a new row/any new data into the SQL table. I suspected it was because workscheduleid wasn't passed but I am not sure.

Comment: Can you share your table structure?

Comment: I got it working already. Thank you so much I used CRUD functions instead.